# by month unix timestamp issue

Tags: php, sql, unix-timestamp

When i pull a monthly report it's only showing entries from the 2nd day of the month up to the day be before the last of the month. For example a report for month of April only shows:

04/02/12 - 04/29/12

What can i modify to show entries:

04/01/12 - 04/30/12

```
$month = $_GET['month'];
if ($services =     $db->get_results("SELECT * from vw_newservices where month(from_unixtime(datetime)) = '$month'")) {
foreach ($services as $service) {
$datetime = date("m/d/y",$service->datetime);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

> Note: If you use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and FROM_UNIXTIME() to convert
>   between TIMESTAMP values and Unix timestamp values, the conversion is
>   lossy because the mapping is not one-to-one in both directions. For
>   example, due to conventions for local time zone changes, it is
>   possible for two UNIX_TIMESTAMP() to map two TIMESTAMP values to the
>   same Unix timestamp value. FROM_UNIXTIME() will map that value back to
>   only one of the original TIMESTAMP values.

See [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

If you want to have unix_timestamps without consideration of time zones, you can calculate it yourself.

In **MySQL**:

From timestamp to unixtime:

```
SELECT timestampdiff(second, '1970-01-01', yourTimestampColumnOrValue);
```

The other way

```
SELECT timestampadd(second, yourTimestampColumnOrValue, '1970-01-01');
```

For **SQL Server** see this [link](http://mysql.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-convert-a-sql-server-datetime-value-to-a-unix-timestamp.html).