# time calculating in a variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, time

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES (NOW(), NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY,?)
```

For `a` and `b` I'm using timestamps while `b` is timestamp `a`, just added plus 14 days.

The problem I got is that I need `c` later on a login script where further queries will be happen when `c` will be downcounted to zero.

Therefore, I thought it would be the best way to find a variable which exactly calculates the difference between `a` and `b` like

```
b - a = c
```

and such a variable will be inserted into the db.

My problem is, that I now have 2 timestamps from the value part which I dont know how to use up to this point. I could get them via fetch_assoc etc. to handle them. But before that, I thought there is maybe an easier way to reach my goal?

Comment: `table` needs to be in quotes because it's a reserved word. If you just changed the table name to simplify the query then please at least keep the syntax valid. Or use `mytable` instead of `table`.

Comment: up to this point its an integer. it depends on what is necessary. i could change that to text, varchar...

Comment: So c is basically b - a in seconds?

Comment: yes. if c will be down to 0 something will happen

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your logic. Could you reform the question so it's easier to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have `c` to be an integer and the difference between `a` and `b` then you can use unix_timestamps (that's the seconds elapsed since 1970-01-01).

```
INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES (NOW(), NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY,unix_timestamp(now()) - unix_timestamp(now() + interval 14 day))
```

To convert such an integer value back to a timestamp you can use the function `FROM_UNIXTIME()`

You can find more info [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: hello, this doesnt work. i tried using this but the query wont take place. when i leave the last part it works. datatype for c is integer with 20 characters.

Comment: curious about that is, that i have set errorreport to e_all but wont get an errormessage for this query. all others are working.

Comment: just print out the query in php and try to run it manually in mysql. e_all refers to php debugging and not to mysql.

Comment: i found the mistake. there was a logical problem for this query. the time to calculate was wrong. instead of calculating [now()] - [now()+14d] it has to be [now()+14d] - [now()]. just another question to understand the whole series. if i use just now, the time will be given in php time, what is exactly the actual time. if i use unix_timestamp it will give me the seconds from the beginning of unix_time. now i have 14000000 for c. but this is not the same in seconds for 14days. it should be 60**60*24*14 = 1.209.600 seconds or am i wrong?

Comment: exactly. it was just the missing unix_timestamp before now. thanks to everybody for helping me.

Comment: I don't understand your question. now() is a MySQL function. Alternatively you can use the keyword CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. The unix_timestamp function also considers time zones, see my other answer for more information (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994643/by-month-unix-timestamp-issue/9996627#9996627). When I do `select unix_timestamp(now() + interval 14 day) - unix_timestamp(now())` the result is 1.209.600 seconds, yes.

Comment: @bonny Glad it works now. Just a hint, it wouldn't hurt, if you would upvote my answer for the extra effort. Thanks :)